# Python vendoring with submodules

Tags: python, python-3.x, git-submodules, python-packaging

I am trying to achieve vendoring with submodules.
I have a library named "rootlib" which uses "mylib" library from "submodules". The "mylib" library is a separate Python package with its own setup.py, so it can be distributed separately. The "mylib" uses the "core" library from its own "submodules" directory.

So the chain of calls looks like this: rootlib -> submodules.mylib -> submodules.core.
The tree looks like this:

```
.
├── rootlib
│   ├── __init__.py
├── submodules
│   └── mylib
│       ├── mylib
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       ├── setup.py
│       ├── submodules
│       │   └── core
│       │       ├── __init__.py
├── setup.py
```

The "rootlib" works when installed to the VENV. I can import its function and use it.
Tests also pass.

But the "mylib" has a problem: the relative import of the "core" library (from ..submodules.core import core_func) does not allow testing the library. I get "ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package".

I also pushed my code to the GIT: https://github.com/litteratum/pypkgvend.

And finally, the question is whether there is a better way to structure it.
Or is there any way to make the "mylib" tests pass?

The goal is to develop "mylib" separately and then include it in the "rootlib" as a GIT submodule.

P.S. the "core" will also be a separate Python library with its own setup.py. I just keep it simpler for this example.

Additional explanation: when I use `from submodules.core import core_func` (without .. at the beginning), the "mylib" library's test pass but the "rootlib" becomes broken: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'submodules.core'".